# Usinga a roman-script font package with LaTeXbangla

Tags: fonts, xetex, indic

How do I use a roman-script font package with LaTeXbangla thorugh XeLaTeX? I wanted to use 'Palatino', by using the standard way I typically add

```
\usepackage{palatino}
```

Also, I tried

```
\setmainfont{Palatino}
\font\pala="Palatino" at 12pt
```

Neither works. It defaults back to Computer Modern.

Here's a sample code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\setlength{\textheight}{9.1in} % \setlength{\columnsep}{0.2in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.50in} % \setlength{\footheight}{0.2in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.3in}  \setlength{\headheight}{0.0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.4in} \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\usepackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush, banglattfont=Siyam Rupali, feature=0, changecounternumbering=0]{latexbangla}
% \usepackage[top=8em, left=10em, right=10em, bottom=8em]{geometry}
\usepackage{verbatim,spverbatim, hyperref, tcolorbox, hologo, enumerate, amsthm, xpatch, amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath, enumerate, chngcntr, pgffor}
\hypersetup{hidelinks=yes}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}


\def\fileversion{v0.2}
\def\filedate{31 October, 2016}
\def\latexbangla{\hologo{LaTeX}\texttt{bangla}}
\newcommand{\pkn}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\addto\captionsbengali{%
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}%
}



 \usepackage{palatino}

\begin{document}


মহা সমস্যা৷

This is a problem. 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable code ...

Answer (score 1):

The `LaTeXbangla` package offers no interface for changing the Latin font. Compile with XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  banglamainfont={Kohinoor Bangla},
  banglattfont={Kohinoor Bangla},% I have no Bengali monospaced font on my system
  feature=0,
  changecounternumbering=0
]{latexbangla}

\newfontfamily{\rmlatin}{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\newfontfamily{\ttlatin}{Latin Modern Mono}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{latin}
 {\ifx\f@family\btt@@name\ttlatin\else\rmlatin\fi}
 {}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

মহা সমস্যা৷

This is not a problem.

\end{document}
```

after changing the fonts to your liking.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. but I'm now having issue with TeX Gyre Pagella. While TeXLive Utility says, it's installed, I get the following error:

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "TeX Gyre Pagella" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................

Comment: @DeepMedhi `\newfontfamily{\rmlatin}{Palatino}` or any font that you can load with XeLaTeX.

Comment: Great \newfontfamily{\rmlatin}{Palatino} works! Thank you!

Comment: One more question: for accent on "e" such as cit\'{e} or  j\"{o}rg, the compile ends with an  error 'LaTeX Error: \begin{latin} on input line 40 ended by \end{document}.' Of course, 'q' mode processes it through. Is there a way to get around this error? Thanks again.

Comment: @DeepMedhi You should type `cité` and `Jörg`.

Comment: I don't want to do this for all the old documents I've that I'm trying to link them together.

Comment: @DeepMedhi Sorry, I see no other way.

Comment: no problem, I was just trying to avoid doing them one at a time for all my old documents; thanks again.

Comment: Oops, sorry, still get the same error if I type as cité and jörg.

Comment: @DeepMedhi Indeed! I'll try and find some workaround.

Comment: @DeepMedhi It's a problem with how `latexbangla` defines the transitions and possibly with `ucharclass` itself.

Comment: Thanks. I suspect also that it's a LaTeXbanga issue. Another side-effect I just found out is that "---" (em-dash) doesn't work either, now that I'm invoking Palatino font. I prefer avoiding replacing "---"
 everywhere with  \textemdash.